# AddForce() not working on velocity-synced object over PhotonNetwork

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I have a player object which has (along with other components and objects) a Rigidbody2D, a Collider2D, a PhotonView, and a script called "PhotonLagCompensationView" attached to it. PhotonLagCompensationView syncs the position and velocity of the attached Rigidbody2D, and applies lag compensation like so:

```
public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(rigidBody2D.position);
            stream.SendNext(rigidBody2D.velocity);
        }
        else
        {
            networkedPosition = (Vector2)stream.ReceiveNext();
            networkedVelocity = (Vector2)stream.ReceiveNext();

            float lag = Mathf.Abs((float)(PhotonNetwork.Time - info.SentServerTime));
            networkedPosition += networkedVelocity * lag;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!photonView.IsMine)
        {
            rigidBody2D.velocity = networkedVelocity;
            rigidBody2D.position = Vector2.Lerp(
                rigidBody2D.position, networkedPosition, Time.fixedDeltaTime * interpolateRate);
        }
    }
```

***The issue*** is when I try to call Rigidbody2D.AddForce() on that GameObject, the velocity wont even stutter. What blows my mind about this though is that when I call the EXACT SAME FUNCTION on a different script, it works just fine on all players in the room.

***The script that is not working*** is "KnockBackOnTrigger" which is attached to an object which is instantiated over the network by the player. This object has a Collider2D which is a trigger, and a PhotonView. The OnTriggerEnter2D callback is working just fine. It prints "trigger", and I've even Debug.logged the AddForce() parameters, and a TryGetComponent<>() to make sure the Rigidbody is being recognized and it's applying force properly. The script applies force like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if(collider.gameObject.layer == 9 && collider.gameObject != PlayerManager.LocalPlayerInstance)
        {
            Debug.Log("trigger");
            collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(
                new Vector2(this.transform.localScale.x * knockBackForce, 0),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

Triggers show up, Rigidbody2D shows up, no moveme

***The script that is working*** is a script attached to the "Lava Blocks" Gameobject which is a tilemap object. The tilemap object for the lava blocks has all the tilemap components attached to it (map, renderer, collider) and they work as intended, as well as the script attached to it. The "LavaBlocks" script works like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {  // everything inside this statement will happen to the player when it touches lava.
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == 9) 
        {
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(
                Vector2.up * upwardForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

So whenever a player touches one of the Lava tiles' collider, it bounces upward.

Additionally, I've tried setting the velocity of the Rigidbody2D, which did not work either. This is in fact what I originally wanted to do with the script, but I tried AddForce() to see if that would work.
At one point I even tried to just use the player's CharacterController2D.Move() function to just smack the player's position some units to the left/right, and even this did not do anything.

Comment: Seems that the difference lies in `collider.gameObject != PlayerManager.LocalPlayerInstance` did you try it without that?

Comment: I could give it a go, but like I said - the if statement is executing properly. It prints the Debug.log() and all the parameters that are being used are showing up properly.

Comment: yes but maybe not for the correct player? ;) Maybe the one for which it is working is getting its value overwritten by `OnPhotonSerializeView`?

Comment: @derHugo my god that was it. I've been pulling my hair out over this for almost a week now. I feel silly now - when the other player would collide with it, that player was the `LocalPlayerInstance` in that instance of the game. My problem now is how am I going to tell that collider who to collide with if not `LocalPlayerInstance`?